# Where is the option saved for always allowing codesign'ing with a particular key?

Tags: xcode

The dialog when provisioning an app for my development device presents the following message (I figure is probably familiar to most app developers):
"codesign wants to sign using key “” in your keychain"

I'm presented with a few options:
"Always allow, allow, and deny"

If I select Always allow -- how is that option remembered? How do I reset it?

This might be a codesign specific issue, but I figure some Xcoders probably are familiar enough with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Xcode in particular, it happened to me to pressed *Deny* by mistake when asking access for codesign access. Here is how I did to solve my issue:

- Open to the keychain
- look for the key `com.apple.gs.xcode.auth.com.apple.account.AppleIDAuthentication.token`
- open it
- click on the *Access Control* tab
- at the bottom there's *Always allow access for these applications:* -> add Xcode in the list
- Don't forget to press `Save Changes`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for finding your way into this. Both answers (including the one from @hamstergene and the ensuing dialogue) helped me a bit. Personally I wish there a bit more "opaqueness" for how Xcode handles this. Or perhaps I just had more knowledge of this system.

Answer (score 0):

Open Keychain, double-click the key item, and check "Access Control" tab. Either change "Confirm..." to "Allow all applications...", or add specific applications into "Always allow access by these applications" list.

Comment: Honestly I have checked this. Am I supposed to be checking the private or the public key? If it's the private key, Xcode is not listed as always being allowed yet the codesign dialog is not presented anymore.

Comment: You need the private one. Are you sure "allow all" does not change the behavior, and the key is correct?

Comment: The only application that is added to the "always allow access" list is "identityservicesd.app" which was there before I selected "always allow".

Comment: Weird, I am pretty sure you need exactly that setting. My guesses: (a) you're changing properties of the wrong key; (b) the key exists in several keychains at once, and codesign picks it from another keychain than where you changed access settings;  (c) keychain's file or permissions are damaged and your changes are not getting saved.

Comment: The only <key> (that's it's exact name) is in my "login" keychain. I have not touched it, but when I reset my Xcode provisioning profile and generate some new certs the prompt is back.